# AnyLogic: Empty agent parameter in the function

Tags: anylogic

I was faced with a problem in AnyLogic.
I created a function with an argument. The argument is agent Message. However, the function doesn't get the current agent. It seems that the argument is empty. Why?

[image: The piece of Main]

[image: The selectOutputIn properties]

[image: SelectFunction properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one of the most confusing things in anylogic that things get calculated in reverse order compared to what you expect.

First the condition is calculated in order for the agent to decide where to go, and after that the agent exits the source...

Based on what we see here, the volume is probably calculated on the "on exit" action of your source and you should calculate it on the "on at exit" or you can also put a delay of 1 milisecond after the source and everything will be ok